# How to use Link - Command in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to jsp and trying to use link-command. I have a page where I need display links. But I was asked to display only 3 links on the page within a section and then provide a "more" link. When user clicks more, it takes them to a new page which will then list all the links that are coming from the database

Say, suppose the database provides 6 links for the product user had selected, the jsp page should link only 3 and a more link. Clicking the more will open a full page with all six links

Currently I am able to disaply all the links coming from the database in the same jsp

Comment: What is "link-command"? Are you asking about paging? Otherwise I'm not sure what the issue is--you have two options, either only expose three links on the first page and all on the next, or use logic in the JSP to loop over the specified number (or all).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically show 3 last links and at jsp generation but some CSS class on all links over 3 first.

If you really want two pages, you can send a post or get parameter to tell the page to show all links or only first ones.